# Utilisation d'« a priori »

Tags: expressions, sens, usage, latin

On a une expression « a priori » qui est beaucoup utilisée dans la vie quotidienne. Que je l’ai beaucoup entendue quand j’étais au cours en français, mais j’arrive pas encore à bien comprendre. Ça semble vouloir dire « en principe », « dans un premiers temps » mais ça m’est pas clair quand même.

Cette expression joue apparemment le rôle d’adverbe ainsi que de nom. Alors je voudrais quelques exemples dans lesquels elle se présente en toute qualité possible.

Comment: L'article de [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_et_a_posteriori) explique bien la provenance ainsi que l'utilisation de l'expression "a priori".

Comment: Tu as bien employé le mot « apparemment » dans ta question ; et bien c'est un synonyme d' « a priori ».

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"A priori" est une locution latine dont le premier sens est "avant toute considération". Elle est parfaitement utile en sciences lors de la formulation d'une hypothèse fondée sur une observation (donc par méthode *hypothético-déductive*). Le Larousse écrit "en se fondant sur des données antérieures à l'expérience".

"A priori" peut à la fois être un adverbe ("a priori c'est un bon film") mais aussi un substantif : dans ce cas, un "a priori" ou "des a priori" (jamais de pluriel aux locutions latines ou étrangères) est un préjugé, un préconçu, une idée reçue. On dit de quelqu'un qu'il est "plein d'a priori".

Comment: Excellente réponse. Juste une nuance : il ne faut pas confondre *un a priori* (ou *un préjugé*) avec *une idée reçue*. Cette dernière est la seule à indiquer une opinion irrationnelle, fondée sur l'autorité. Il **n'est pas** irrationnel, malsain ou fallacieux d'avoir autant de préjugés (ou d'a priori) qu'on veut. L'irrationalité commence quand on prend ses préjugés pour autre chose que ce qu'ils sont : des intuitions à confirmer/infirmer plus tard par des observations et des raisonnements. Ce qu'indique d'ailleurs le début de ta réponse avec la référence aux sciences.

Comment: Merci de la précision !

Comment: Une « hypothèse fondée sur une observation » serait _a posteriori_, au moins dans une certaine mesure. _A posteriori_ est le contraire de _a priori_.

Comment: Si on part du particulier (une observation) au général (la règle), c'est bien de l'a priori, car il n'existe rien de matériel ou scientifique pour prouver l'hypothèse en question.

Answer (score 0):

Non on dit des aprioris (ça s'accorde!), car il s'agit d'un composé

Comment: Bon! Cela mériterait certainement un plus ample développement car oui, ton observation est intéressante, ne serait-ce que pour un machin ayant depuis longtemps un sacré historique d'incertitudes orthographiques... ;-)

Comment: Quelles sources ?